# How does every real number have a decimal representation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, decimal-expansion

I am a little bit confused at how every real number can have at least one decimal representation, because:

- There are uncountable many real numbers
- There are countable strings of infinite length over a finite alphabet

I would expect that there can be no injection from the real numbers to the infinite strings over `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,.}`.
Is there a mistake in my assumption or reasoning? Does this only mean that some different real numbers must have the same decimal representation?

Comment: The second statement is false even for the alphabet {$0,1$} Cantor's diagonal method shows that there are uncountable many infinite long words. The set of finitely long words over some finite alphabet however is countable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second point is not correct. There are uncountably many strings of *infinite* length, even though there are only countably many strings of *finite but unbounded* length. This makes sense because the latter correspond to terminating decimals, which are a subset of the rationals.

You can see by diagonal argument that the set of infinite strings is uncountable: assume it is countable, and order the strings $s_1,s_2,\ldots$, then construct a string which is different to $s_1$ in position $1$, different to $s_2$ in position $2$, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The *number of digits* in any *given* infinite decimal representation is *countably* infinite (and equal to the cardinality of the naturals).

The *number* of *possible* infinite decimal *representations* is *uncountably* infinite (and equal to the cardinality of the continuum).